# Loop-ing mutiple values with the use of 1 instance from a data class

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, data-class

I am trying to figure out how to loop a data class. I have a function called getAges() which contains a listof Ages from 1 - 10. Each age are called from a data class called Age, which should be an Int. How can I successfully loop through Age with different numbers, for ex 1-10? Appreciate the feedback!

My Data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "dropdown_age")
data class Age(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
    val age: Int?
)
```

My Function called getAges:

```
class ProfileViewModel: Viewmodel() {
    fun getAges() = listOf(

        Age(1), Age(2), Age(3), Age(4), Age(5),
        Age(6), Age(7), Age(8), Age(9), Age(10),

                         )
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a list of Age instances with values 1..10 without hosting to manually create each one like you’re doing above?

Comment: yes, that is exactly it! Didnt know how to formulate it properly @Tenfour04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a List "constructor" function that can be used to create a List using a lambda where the lambda parameter is an index, starting at 0. (I use quotation marks for constructor because interfaces don't have true constructors. This is just a function that looks like a constructor because of how it is capitalized.)

```
fun getAges() = List(10) { Age(it + 1) }
```

Or you can use the `map` function with a range. `map` modifies each item out of any Iterable to produce a new List.

```
fun getAges() = (1..10).map { Age(it) }

// or

fun getAges() = (1..10).map(::Age)
```

Comment: Alright, will try it out and see if it works!

Comment: It works as intended! Sorry for the ambiguity of the question but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using collections api [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html#foreach)

```
 getAges().forEach{
     println(it.age)
 }
```

Or using normal For loop

```
 for (age: Age in getAges()) {
     println(age.age)
 }
```

Comment: but if I am using forEach, how do I specify between what values I want ? In my case 1..10

Comment: You are returning values you want inside `getAges()` right? So using it as a data source will loop thgrough those values

Comment: well I am calling the getAges() function after from within a composable like so: val list = converterViewModel.getAges()

Comment: Than use that same `list` variable. I am not sure what is confusing you, you should probably rephrase your question

Comment: I updated the fun since its within a class!

Comment: This is the error I get when placing a For loop inside the class with the function: "For is not an expression, and only expressions are allowed here"

Comment: Can you be more specific what is that you want to do.

Comment: Exactly like @Tenfour04 stated:
 "how to create a list of Age instances with values 1..10 without hosting to manually create each one"

Comment: Instead of creating an instance of Age with a value/Int for every age/Int per age, how can I loop it using 1 instance of Age but with multiple values (1..10) ?